Characters break through the animation frame and chase each other across motion picture frames
I'm looking to identify an old cartoon (from the 1930s or 1940s, I think, based on the style) that had the characters breaking through the animation frame and chasing each other across the motion picture frames. It's very chaotic (and extremely funny).
What I remember about it is that projectionists used to hate this film, as the movement across the frames made it look like the film had slipped out of the projector.
Which animation short is this?

I remember this being a running gag for one of the "big" studios during chases to depict characters being unable to take a corner and drift off/outside the movie. It's either been one of the MGM/Tex Avery cartoons (Droopy?) or Bugs Bunny. I think it's been MGM, although I'm not 100% sure and can't pin it down right now.

I don't believe it was from one of the major studios, and it was definitely in black & white.

It's been reused (not 1:1), unless you're talking about a different effect.

A very famous iteration of a cartoon character breaking through the 4th wall is Daffy Duck's Duck Amuck.

It was considered a relatively advanced technique at the time, and is certainly one of the most memorable of Daffy's Iterations. 
It was even voted the #2 Cartoon of all time.

[It stars] Daffy Duck, who is tormented by a seemingly sadistic, initially unseen animator (who turns out to be Bugs Bunny), who constantly changes Daffy's locations, clothing, voice, physical appearance and even shape. Pandemonium reigns throughout the cartoon as Daffy attempts to steer the action back to some kind of normality, only for the animator to either ignore him or, more frequently, to over-literally interpret his increasingly frantic demands.

Daffy Duck would chase characters, paintbrushes, and be chased himself across varying frames and negative space, whilst giving instructions to the animator.

While I love this cartoon, it's not the one I was thinking of; in particular, the one I'm thinking of is black & white, and it doesn't feature any famous characters (that I recall).
